# How to use package `RcppExamples`?

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm new to Rcpp and want to export some C++ class into R. I've install `RcppExmples` intending to learn some code snippet. But I didn't even know how to use it? `help(RcppExamples)` only to get:

> Description:
>
> ```
> This package shows some simple examples for the use of ‘Rcpp’.
> Both the older ('classic') and new API are documented.
>
> It can also serve as a working template to create packages that
> use ‘Rcpp’ to interface C++ code or libraries.
> ```

Where can I get the examples?

Comment: -1 for not doing basic research (i.e. reading the manual).

Comment: It is in the *source code* of the package.

Comment: For anybody who is not deep ionto R and Rcpp it is not clear that you have to look at the source, you could expect a `demo` or `example` like on other packages. I just red the manual and was pretty happy to find this post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sources for the examples in the package are, well, in the package itself.

This is Rcpp. It works with C++ source code, and R code.  You don't use this like a normal package, you create packages with it.  From source.

Answer (score 2):

Did you had a look at the [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppExamples/RcppExamples.pdf)? I think it's clear from this document. But the DESCRIPTION file says:

> Note that the documentation in this package currently does not cover all the features in the package. It is not even close.

So I fear that's all you can get - besides looking at the [source code](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/RcppExamples_0.1.4.tar.gz).

Comment: Thanks! BTW, is there a way to invoke the manual from the R shell?

Comment: With `help(package=RcppExample)` you can at least see all the function in the package and invoke the help page for each function manually.